# Using atmega16 to reduce a DC motor speed with cytron md10c motor driver

Tags: avr, atmega16

So I have this DC motor which I want to reduce it's speed to 25% so obviously I used phase correct pwm to do so via the motor driver , I was able to do it through timer1 but my assistant professor wants me to do it with the 8-bit timer0 so I wrote the code and it ran but in full so my question is there are some calculation that must be done before writing the code and if there are , what are these calculations ?

Note : motor frequency is 100-250 Hz
I am working with internal frequency 1 MHz and prescaler 1024

```
 #define F_CPU 1000000UL

 #include <avr/io.h>

 #include <util/delay.h>

int main(void)
{

DDRB  = DDRB | (1<<PB3); //set OC0 as output pin --> pin where the PWM signal is generated from MC

/*set CS02:0 to 101 to work with 1024 prescaler
set WGM0[1:0] to 01 to work with phase correct,pwm
set COM01:0 to 11 to Set OC0 on compare match when up-counting. Clear OC0 on compare match
when downcounting*/

    TCCR0 = 0b00111101;
   OCR0 = 64; // 25% DUTY CYCLE
    while (1)
{
    ;
}
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question actually forces us to guess a bit - You're not telling enough facts to really help you. So, I'll *guess* you're using fast PWM, and *guess* you're controlling the motor speed with the PWM duty cycle.

Motor frequency and prescaler values are actually not so interesting - If you want to have speed reduction, you want to change the *duty cycle*, I assume.

A duty cycle of 25% of a 16-bit timer ist $10000/4 = $4000 (I guess that's what you set the Output compare register of your 16 bit timer to)

Obviously, on an 8-bit timer, a duty cycle of 25% is $100/4 = $40.

Also note what you need to write into TCCR0 to achieve the same thing from timer 0 is entirely different from what you write to TCCR1 for pretty much the same action - The bit positions are 100% different. Consult the data sheet, I think you got that wrong.

Comment: Then next add an oscilloscope view on how your output voltage looks like.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reach an oscilloscope , look my main problem is when I connected it to timer0 it worked but in full speed but with timer1 it worked as I hoped so what I think there's something wrong with my code @tofro

Comment: TCCR0 is nothing more than the timer register which you fill to your selected mode and prescaler in another meaning for initializing the timer